# Void.delete() (discord.JS v13)

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

so I know the problem, I just dont know a solution for this.
The console.log says: TypeError: msg.delete is not a function

I know msg is a void, so thats why it doesnt work.

Im thankful for every help!

My code looks like this:

```
message.channel.bulkDelete(messages);
        
message.channel.send("Messages getting purged...")
.then((sentMessage) => setTimeout(function () { 

sentMessage.edit(` **${amount}** messages were purged!`) 

}))
.then((msg) => setTimeout(function () { msg.delete() }, 6000)
```

Comment: Are you trying to delete the ``x amount messages were purged!`` message?

Comment: Yes Im trying to delete it after 6000 ms

Comment: Is there any reason you unaccepted my answer? Is there any problem with it?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `msg` is not the message you sent, but the [timeout ID](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) as you return it here: `(sentMessage) => setTimeout()`.

Try to return the `sentMessage` so you an grab it in your next `then()`:

```js
message.channel
  .send('Messages getting purged...')
  .then(sentMessage => {
    setTimeout(function () {
      sentMessage.edit(` **${amount}** messages were purged!`);
    });
    return sentMessage;
  })
  .then(msg =>
    setTimeout(function () {
      msg.delete();
    }, 6000),
  );
```

It would be probably better to use async/await here though (just make sure you're inside an async function):

```js
try {
  // send a message that messages are being deleted
  const sentMessage = await message.channel.send('Messages getting purged...');

  // delete the messages and wait for them to be deleted
  const deletedMessages = await message.channel.bulkDelete(messages);

  // edit the sent message when finished
  await sentMessage.edit(`**${deletedMessages.size}** messages were purged!`);

  // delete the message after 6 seconds
  setTimeout(() => sentMessage.delete(), 6000);
} catch (err) {
  message.channel.send(`Oops, there was an error`);
  console.log(err);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and help! :)

Answer (score 1):

```js
message.channel.bulkDelete(messages);
        
message.channel.send("Messages getting purged...")
.then((sentMessage) => setTimeout(function () { 

sentMessage.edit(`**${amount}** messages were purged!`).then((msg) => setTimeout(function () { msg.delete() }, 6000)

}))
```